# Subversion as software deployment

Tags: svn, deployment

I would like to deploy the a compiled software globally.

Since I already had a subversion server for code versioning control, I intend to use SVN for software deployment. However since many people uses apt-get for software deployment, I would like to see the pros and cons of using SVN over `apt-get`.

Comment: This is like asking "is a banana a better orange than an apple?"

Comment: I think there must be reason people use 'apt-get' over SVN. And I would like to understand the reason behind. Therefore I seek for answers from other developer.

Comment: @Winston Can you explain how you intend to use SVN for deployment?

Comment: @Winston SVN is a [version control system](http://linux.die.net/man/1/svn) primarily.  While apt-get is a [package handling utility](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) that knows if there are dependent packages.  You can use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't check in compiled code into Subversion! This is especially true with packages (RPM or .deb).

What I've seen is people store their packages in Subversion, then use either a Web-SVN browser to specify the URL, or do a *checkout* and put the package on their local system. I do not recommend this.

The reason is simple: Compiled binary takes up a lot of room. Our RPM packages could be hundreds of megabytes in size. Every time you commit one into Subversion, you increase the size of your repository by a few hundred megabytes. After a few releases, you have gigabytes worth of binaries in your repository.

And for what? You can't *diff* binaries in Subversion. You can't look at their history and see anything useful. And, binaries have a short shelf life. This is especially true where it's common to do releases multiple times per month. You end up with a bloated repository that must be maintained, and 90% of it is information that no one cares about.

Yet, people do this because it's convenient. You give someone the Subversion URL, and they can download it. Big deal. If you had a dedicated release server, they can do the same thing, and it will be faster. And, you can delete the older releases that no one needs anymore and save gigabytes worth of space.

Just because a lot of people do something doesn't mean you should too. A lot of people do heroin too, and I don't recommend that either.

Do you have a build server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)? If you do, store your compiled packages there. You can delete the older packages (Jenkins will do that for you), and keep a connection between the source code and the package.

At one place where I worked, we setup Jenkins with the [Promoted Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). When we did a release, we would go into the Jenkins build, and *promote* it. The promotion would tag our source code, lock the build to prevent Jenkins from deleting the archived package, and send the package over to our apt-get server. Even better, we would mark the build with the release number. You could go into Jenkins, find the build that was released, review the source code, download the package, and see all the changes between one build and the next.

Our Subversion repository contained only source, and users could use an actual apt-get package server for automatic package updates.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information. It seems to me that the question is not similar to "a banana a better orange than an apple?"

Answer (score 0):

SVN contains the source, whereas apt-get will take care of all the installation for the product. Usually when using SVN you'd only be able to get a copy of the software and would need to install it yourself, manually.

Hope this helps.